Spell Check Configuration iOS
TextFormField(
        spellCheckConfiguration: SpellCheckConfiguration(
          misspelledSelectionColor: Colors.red,
          spellCheckService: DefaultSpellCheckService(),
        ),
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        controller: descriptionController,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
        maxLines: 4,
        maxLength: 250,
        maxLengthEnforcement: MaxLengthEnforcement.enforced,
        onSaved: (newValue) =>
            campaignPostViewController.setDescription(newValue!),
        style: TextStyle(color: ColorConstants.white, fontSize: 14.sp),
        focusNode: campaignPostViewController.descriptionFocusNode,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'your hint',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          ),
          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        ),
      )

The Spell check configuration is not working in iOS
Tried with CupertinoTextfield and normal Textfield.
expected output is with the red curvy underline for the mispelled words on typing on the field.
